# Using the Default Payment Form with Authorize.Net Accept Hosted Payment Page

Tags: payment-gateway, authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

I am integrating Authorize.NET with my web application. I am using the Hosted Payment Form as described here:

I would like to use the default Payment form as described in the settings page: https://sandbox.authorize.net/UI/themes/sandbox/Settings/SettingsPayFormMain.aspx I would like to customize this payment form by passing relevant fields.

I am using the following JSON object:

```
{
  "getHostedPaymentPageRequest": {
    "merchantAuthentication": {
      "name": "api_key",
      "transactionKey": "transaction_key"
    },
    "transactionRequest": {
      "transactionType": "authCaptureTransaction",
      "amount": "20.00",
      "profile": {
        "customerProfileId": "123456789"
      },
      "customer": {
        "email": "ellen@mail.com"
      },
      "billTo": {
        "firstName": "Ellen",
        "lastName": "Johnson",
        "company": "Souveniropolis",
        "address": "14 Main Street",
        "city": "Pecan Springs",
        "state": "TX",
        "zip": "44628",
        "country": "USA"
      }
    },
    "hostedPaymentSettings": {
      "setting": [{
        "settingName": "hostedPaymentReturnOptions",
        "settingValue": "{\"showReceipt\": true, \"url\": \"https://example.com/receipt\", \"urlText\": \"Continue\", \"cancelUrl\": \"https://example.com/cancel\", \"cancelUrlText\": \"Cancel\"}"
      },  {
        "settingName": "hostedPaymentShippingAddressOptions",
        "settingValue": "{\"show\": false, \"required\": false}"
      }, {
        "settingName": "hostedPaymentBillingAddressOptions",
        "settingValue": "{\"show\": true, \"required\": false}"
      }, {
        "settingName": "hostedPaymentCustomerOptions",
        "settingValue": "{\"showEmail\": false, \"requiredEmail\": false, \"addPaymentProfile\": true}"
      }, {
        "settingName": "hostedPaymentOrderOptions",
        "settingValue": "{\"show\": true, \"merchantName\": \"G and S Questions Inc.\"}"
      }, {
        "settingName": "hostedPaymentIFrameCommunicatorUrl",
        "settingValue": "{\"url\": \"https://example.com/special\"}"
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

I am receiving the following Payment form which doesn't looks professional. Any idea how to use the default payment form from Authorize.NET

[image]

**Default Form**
[image]

HTML FORM used:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="https://test.authorize.net/payment/payment" id="formAuthorizeNetTestPage" name="formAuthorizeNetTestPage">
        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="Replace with form token from getHostedPaymentPageResponse" />
        Continue to Authorize.Net to Payment Page
        <button id="btnContinue">Continue to next page</button>
    </form>         
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you asking if you can customize the look of the form?

Comment: Yes, I would like to use the Default form with some customization to it.I would like to use the payment form that comes default with Authorize.Net with some customization like Title etc

Comment: So why don't use use the self hosted form where you can control the look and feel of the entire form? It's a bit more work but then you have full control over the process.

Comment: I want to use the self-hosted form(Default Form in my question). But, I end up getting the form in the top with no header, title, design whatsoever. I don't know how to make sure, the self-hosted form is used for the payment.

Comment: @JohnConde, Thanks a lot. All I really want is the default form from Authorize.Net. I really don't want to customize it. But, when I post `token` to https://accept.authorize.net/payment/payment, I get an ugly looking payments page straight out of phishing site.

Answer (score 3):

The Authorize.Net accept.js hosted form cannot be customized in the way you would like it to be. That's by design. It is intended for businesses/developers who do not have the technical know how to do a more complicated, even if only slightly, implementation of a checkout page.

The self-hosted accept.js form can be customized *completely* and still keep our site outside of PCI scope because the credit card data never passes through your server.

To summarize, the Authorize.Net-hosted form cannot be customized in the manner you are looking to do. *But* that shouldn't be necessary as you can accomplish the same thing and stay out of PCI scope by using the self-hosted version of that form.

---

This is the code I use to get the hosted payment form which appears how you want it to. If you do not see the same page I do, verify you have the correct URL in the form action. Below is the Sandbox URL. The production URL is `https://accept.authorize.net/payment/payment`.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hosted Accept.js Payment Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="paymentForm" method="POST" action="https://test.authorize.net/payment/payment">
        <input type="hidden" name="token" id="token" value="YOUR_TOKEN_HERE" />
        <button onclick="sendPaymentDataToAnet()">Go to Authorize.Net hosted payment form</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I really dont want to customize the payment form at all. I want to display the default form with Authorize.NET which is described here: https://sandbox.authorize.net/UI/themes/sandbox/Settings/SettingsPayFormMain.aspx

Comment: Very simple question, how do I let my clients see the default payment form to make the payment?  I don't want to make any customization. Any pointers would be really helpful.

Comment: That's a different question then what you have asked above. You also seem to be able to get a default payment form to display so I am unsure what you are actually looking for.

Comment: The default payment form looks different from what I am getting currently. I want the exact same form style-wise.

Comment: Show your HTML as when I try to duplicate this  I get the form you expect to see

Comment: I am using the HTML form shown here : https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/accept_hosted.html#Integrating_the_Form_using_a_Redirect. Modifying the question to show the HTML used

Comment: "keep our site outside of PCI scope" - Unfortunately, this is not true. Using a custom form with Accept.js [puts a service in the scope of PCI SAQ A-EP](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/accept.html).

Answer (score 0):

The payment page you are looking for is an old page which Authorize used to provide and now they moved to new one. as per their website old url was https://secure.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll to get the old page but it is now deprecated. please see this link for what has been changed https://developer.authorize.net/api/upgrade_guide.html